# How to push particular key values of array into other array one by one on click a button in angular/javascript

Tags: angular

I have an array of object marrayval, from that array I need to take the values of 'country' and need to push one by one instead of all elements into arrayval after every click.Ex - For first click need to push C1,then next click need to push c1,C2 then c1,c2,c3.. so on till end. Here is the code below https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjzdqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

### app.component.html

```html
    <div (click)="getArray()">Click</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```js
    import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'testapp';
      arrayval = [];
      userName:any;
      constructor() { }
      marrayval = [{"id":1,"country":"C1","count":2},{"id":2,"country":"C2","count":1},{"id":3,"country":"C3","count":1}];
     
      ngOnInit() {
     
      }
     
    getArray(){
     this.marrayval.forEach((element) => {
         console.log(element);
                 this.arrayval.push(element.country);    
             });
              console.log(this.arrayval);
      }
     
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "testapp";
  arrayval = [];
  userName: any;
  constructor() {}
  marrayval = [
    { id: 1, country: "C1", count: 2 },
    { id: 2, country: "C2", count: 1 },
    { id: 3, country: "C3", count: 1 }
  ];

      stackArray = [];

      ngOnInit() {
        this.stackArray = this.marrayval.reverse();
      }

      getArray() {
        if (this.stackArray.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.arrayval.push(this.stackArray.pop().country);
        console.log(this.arrayval);
      }
    }
```

I have also updated the here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjzdqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
// click 1: [c1]
// click 2: [c1, c2]
// click 3: [c1, c2, c3]
// click 4: [c1, c2, c3]
// click 5: [c1, c2, c3]

this.arrayval =
   this.marrayval
  .filter((_, index) => index <= this.arrayval.length)
  .map(element => element.country);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, Where do I need to add this , I am getting some error getArray(){
 this.marrayval = [
  ...this.marrayval,
  ...this.marrayval.map(element => element.country)
 ]
     console.log(this.arrayval);
  }

Comment: I don't know you want to do that. but i never do something like it. Because after merge there is 2 type in one list. Maybe it is typescript type error.

Comment: I have created demo , Can you please update here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjzdqc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I just updated it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2e56j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You are pushing all elements c1,c2,c3 at a time.but as per requirement we need to push first c1 only once we click,then c1,c2 once we click, then c1,c2,c3 once we click..

Comment: i updated it again. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2e56j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

**I think this you want. Try this**

```js
marrayval = [
    { id: 1, country: "C1", count: 2 },
    { id: 2, country: "C2", count: 1 },
    { id: 3, country: "C3", count: 1 }
  ];
arrayval = [];
this.marrayval.reverse();
  
function getArray() {
        if (this.marrayval.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.arrayval.push(this.marrayval.pop().country);
        console.log(this.arrayval);
      }
```

```css
button {
  background: #0095ff;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="getArray()">Click me</button>
```